# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение:
"Он, и только он(,) ― виновник всего".
Нужна ли запятая перед тире? По-моему, нужна, поскольку "только он" - оборот уточнения, который следует закрыть. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае это не уточнение( уточняется широкое понятие через узкое:Там, на поляне; Он, этот парень из местных), не присоединение в чистом виде(было бы присоединением в таком виде: Он виновник всего, и только он.Присоединение - "послемыслие" - что-то сказал, а потом добавил то, что упустил сразу ), но интонация присоединения есть.Здесь же другая пунктограмма - "знаки препинания при повторяющихся словах".Пунктуация, как здесь уже справедливо заметили, зависит от автора и его чтения: есть пауза - ставим запятую, нет паузы - нет запятой.Тире тоже возможно при логическом подчёркивании автора. Так что возможны все варианты: 
Он, и только он, ― виновник всего.
Он, и только он виновник всего.(Я бы этот вариант предпочла)
Он, и только он - виновник всего.
Он и только он виновник всего.

Answer (score 3):

Тире не ставится, так как подлежащее выражено местоимением. Конечно, это правило можно нарушать, если того требует интонация, но в вашем лучше звучит без тире.   
Запятые в подобном предложении сомнительны. Всё зависит от того, как рассматривать конструкцию *"и только он"*. Если второе *"он"* принять за подлежащее, то запятые не нужны вообще, а если за уточнение — ставятся обе запятые, даже если автор захочет, чтобы было тире. Конечно, довольно странно принимать *"и только он"* за уточнение, поэтому я считаю, что лучше здесь не ставит никаких знаков препинания.

Answer (score 3):

Хочу напомнить, что союз "и" может употребляться в присоединительном значении "и притом". Вся конструкция с этим союзом называется присоединительной и обособляется. Ну а тире здесь не ставится, так как подлежащее выражено личным местоимением.
"Он, и только он, виновник всего".